# QTableWidgetItem move cursor to a cell (not select only)

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

My task is simple. In the table, move to the next row after user writes number and pressed enter key.

I have **QTableWidget** with **key event** that is getting **cursor position from signal**:

```
connect(ui->table->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), key, SLOT(cell_position(QModelIndex)));
```

Key event:

```
...
if ( (key->key()==Qt::Key_Enter) ) {
...
```

QTableWidgetItem:

```
...        
QTableWidgetItem *item = table->item(m_pos, n_pos);
        if(item == nullptr)
            {
             QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
             table->setItem(m_pos, n_pos, item);
             item->setSelected(1);
...
```

But it gives me this behaviour - it selects the cell under currently entered cell. The cursor remains on its position.

[image: setSelected behaviour]

Please, do you have any idea how to move cursor down? I tried some QTableWidgetItem methods but did not find any suitable one.

Thanks.

Update:
Instead of

```
item->setSelected(1);
```

I use

```
table->setCurrentItem(item);
```

which does what I need. It move cursor to the item cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the current item, and you can do it calling the `QTableWidget::setCurrentItem()` method.

See [QTableWidget::setCurrentItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCurrentItem)

Answer (score 0):

The function you should use to set the current index is

QModelIndex position;

table->setCurrentIndex(position);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).